# XFS superblock not found

Tags: data-recovery, xfs, superblock

I had an old drive beginning to fail and my backups were no good apparently.
I got a new drive larger than the failed one and was able to ddrescue it over, with bad/missing superblocks of course.
Through some fiddling around I was able to mount the new drive, but there were errors of course displayed on a directory listing. I began to copy what I could, and I'm assuming subdirectories had issues, because it errored mid-copy on the new drive and the partition stopped responding.
I cannot get xfs_repair to salvage the new drive saying to secondary superblocks were found.

What are my options here?

I suppose I could ddrescue off the old drive again, which unfortunately took over a day last time, but even then how do I proceed?  Running testdisk/photorec would be a nightmare.

Comment: It is not very clear to me why you can't get xfs_repair, in some extreme case xfs_repair -L working.

Comment: I previously (before partial success mounting the partition) tried the -L flag with the same results (no secondary superblock) but just started it again because why not?  Worst case I start over with ddrescue.

Comment: consider using readonly mounts and/or snapshots / [copy-on-write overlays](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Recovering_a_damaged_RAID#Making_the_harddisks_read-only_using_an_overlay_file) so you don't have to repeate ddrescue after every botched experiment. with snapshots you can just revert any changes made. unfortunately its very difficult to tell remotely what else could be done, it depends on how much data is missing where / the specific nature of the corruption. you can also try your luck with `xfsdump`.